# Wrong Date coming when i formatting the string to date

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

When i try format string to date i was given one day but that output showing different date please any one is helping for that.

```
    let my_date = "22-03-1995"
    let dateformat = DateFormatter()
    dateformat.dateFormat = "DD-MM-yyyy"
    let date = dateformat.date(from: my_date)
    print(date!)
    text_lbl.text = "\(date!)"
```

My Output is: 1995-01-21 comes like this.

Comment: `DD`, uppercase `D` is for the day of the year, not the day of the month. See the doc: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns Once fix, you might have a "one day difference", that's due to TimeZone.

Comment: @Larme thanks for your quick reply here formatting date as well comes in wrong format when i give date only come's first but here years come's first

Comment: Because that's a `Date` object. That's normal. If you want a custom "date representation UX", you need to specify the format you want, using a custom `dateFormat`. So currently, use the same `DateFormatter`, and change its `dateFormat` to the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
let my_date = "22-03-1995"
let dateformat = DateFormatter()
dateformat.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let date = dateformat.date(from: my_date)
print(date!)
```

This will gives you `1995-03-22 00:00:00 +0000` as a result

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply  let my_date = "22-03-1995"
        let dateformat = DateFormatter()
        dateformat.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let date = dateformat.date(from: my_date)
        print(date!)
        text_lbl.text = "\(date!)"  But still come's in wrong date.

Comment: What are you getting as a response, once you have changed the format?

Answer (score -1):

```
func changeDateFormatFor(date : String,fromFormat : String = "dd-MM-yyyy", toFormat : String = "yyyy-MM-dd")-> String{
if date == "" {
    return ""
}
dateFormatter.dateFormat = fromFormat
let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = toFormat
let str = dateFormatter.string(from: date1!)
return str
```

}

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to OP and to future readers of the Q&A ) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of dumping some code only.